# While loop end immediately after putting one string in my list (tic-tac-toe)

Tags: python

Im doing a tic-tac-toe project for the university in Python, but if I put one String on my List, my while loop break immediately, although I have inserted an "and" in my "if" sentence. Whats the problem here?

My idea was that if someone have the strings on a winning position like in tic-tac-toe, my while loop will stop because I put "spiel" to false. but if I put already one string in there, my if sentence will already be triggered and the game ends

```
while spiel == True:
    print(player1 + " fängt an! ")
    eingabe = input("Auf welchem Feld möchtest du dein " + zeichen1 + " setzen?: ")
    eingabe = eingabe.upper()
    if eingabe == "A1":
        field[1][1] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "A2":
        field[2][1] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "A3":
        field[3][1] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B1":
        field[1][3] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B2":
        field[2][3] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B3":
        field[3][3] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C1":
        field[1][5] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C2":
        field[2][5] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C3":
        field[3][5] = zeichen1
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    print(player2 + " du bist dran!")
    eingabe = input("Auf welchem Feld möchtest du dein " + zeichen2 + " setzen?: ")
    eingabe = eingabe.upper()
    if eingabe == "A1":
        field[1][1] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "A2":
        field[2][1] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "A3":
        field[3][1] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B1":
        field[1][3] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B2":
        field[2][3] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "B3":
        field[3][3] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C1":
        field[1][5] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C2":
        field[2][5] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
    elif eingabe == "C3":
        field[3][5] = zeichen2
        i = 0
        while i < len(field):
            print(field[i])
            i += 1
if zeichen1 in (field[1][1] and field[1][3] and field[1][5]) or (field[2][1] and field[2][3] and field[2][5]) or (field[3][1] and field[3][3] and field[3][5]) or (field[1][1] and field[2][3] and field[3][5]) or (field[3][1] and field[2][3] and field[1][5]):
    print(player1 + " hat gewonnen!")
    spiel = False
```

I expect that my code end, after someone win the round in tic-tac-toe and not end already if I add one string in

Comment: Where's the `while` loop? I suggest to [add in the question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/58216375/edit) the whole `while` loop

Comment: please give a minimum example that people can run to reproduce your problem

Comment: At the moment you're testing `if (zeichen1 in (...)) or (...)` i.e. your `zeichen1` is only being tested in the first set of `and` statements.  Try `if 'foo' in 'bar' or 'baz'` and note it evaluates as true.

Comment: Your tests for tic winning position using zeihen1 in (...) is in error.  Here's an (example of checking for tic tac toe in Python)[https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-implementation-automatic-tic-tac-toe-game-using-random-number/]

Comment: Given how it's indented, your code should actually go in an infinite loop. Please post a _proper_ [mcve].

Comment: This being said (assuming your real code is properly indented), the answer is in steve's comment.